# Displaying Query data in a TextInput Field in Flex?

Tags: database, apache-flex, textinput

I'm trying to display query data into multiple TextInput Fields in Flex.

```
<mx:TextInput id="stagInput" text="{acContacts}" width="170" x="120" y="74"/>
```

This is what I'm trying but all that displays is [object Object]

I think I need to define the database field I'm wanting to display, but I'm unsure how to do this as TextInput fields don't support dataField or labelField properties. Is there another property I don't know about?

How do i go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I would like user to have the ability to edit old information. So once they click edit profile a form will appear displaying all their previous information like first name, last name, email ect. This information will be displayed in its own TextInput field so users can make the changes.

The information is being provided by a database using a query and an array collection. I'm just unsure how i go about taking the queried array collection information and display it into TextInput Fields.

I hope that explains it a little better and I look forward to any input that could help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I was looking for

```
[Bindable]
    private var acCon:ArrayCollection;

    private function reData():void //RETRIEVE DATA
    {
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConn;
        stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM person";
        stmt.execute();
        var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
        acCon = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
    }

<mx:Repeater id="repeater1" dataProvider="{acCon}"> 
<mx:Label id="Label1" text="{repeater1.currentItem.lastname}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is acContacts the object? You can try {acContacts.label} or {acContacts.name} (or whatever attribute you wish to display).

Comment: Sorry acContacts is ArrayCollection.

For example I'd like to display the field fname from the database but just adding {acContacts.fname} the way you suggested doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: What is an ArrayCollection of? Can you give me a description of your data?

Comment: The array collection is a query to a database containing fields like first name and last name... I'm post my code in an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest to override the toString():String function. You can create a small subclass for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a bit more of my code

```
[Bindable]
private var acContacts:ArrayCollection;
private function retrieveData():void { //RETRIEVE DATA
    var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConn;
    stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE person_id=1";
    stmt.execute();
    var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
    acContacts = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
}
```

`<mx:TextInput id="stagInput" text="{acContacts}" width="170" x="120" y="74"/>`

The data comming from the query is information like first and last name, email, website .ect

I realize that my query currently has a hardcoded id but right now I'm just trying to get the users information displaying individual Textinputs - eg. one for first name one for last name .ect

Hope this explains my problem a bit better.

Thanks Again!